# How to find index of an item in a List<> where two or more property need to be check

Tags: c#, search, indexing, find

How to find index of an item in a List<> where ***two or more property*** need to be checked?

This works:

```
int index = myList.FindIndex(a => a.Prop == oProp);
```

This doesn't work:

```
int index = myList.FindIndex(a => a.Prop1 == oProp1 && a => a.Prop2 == oProp2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
int index = myList.FindIndex(a => a.Prop1 == oProp1 && a.Prop2 == oProp2);
```

Comment: Thanks for help :)